# is it possible to make a docker image from a debian image

Tags: docker, debian, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am using google compute engine and want to use `kubernetes` 
I have created an image for my machine without using dockers.
The command I used is

```
sudo gcimagebundle -d /dev/sda -o /tmp/ --log_file=/tmp/ansible.log
```

it results in this image file

```
6820b8b74dba0d115e3f9e0b969055ac6b67bc65.image.tar.gz
```

Is is possible to create a `Dockerfile` that creates a docker image from that image.

Or Do i have to create an empty docker image from debian and install of of my dependencies on it ? because I really prefer not to install all of my dependencies again (it's a day's work)

any solution?

edit : 
tried this :

```
>> cat 6820b8b74dba0d115e3f9e0b969055ac6b67bc65.image.tar.gz | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Unhandled tar header type 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know gcimagebundle, but if it simply bundels the all files in a tar, without additional metadata this should work

```
FROM scratch
ADD 6820b8b74dba0d115e3f9e0b969055ac6b67bc65.image.tar.gz /
```

But it would be better if you would have an Dockerfile, because then it would be easy to make changes to the image and it would be reproducible.

Comment: hi @Julian , getting this `cat my.image.tar.gz | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Unhandled tar header type 83`

Comment: what is the complete dockerFile ? ADD justs adds the file to the docker image . how do you extract it ?

Comment: COPY only adds the File, ADD can extract it. It seems like an custum tar Format. Maybe try extract it by Hand und then copy it

Answer (score 0):

You can tar your filesystem, and then

- you can use ADD in a dockerfile, like it has been said before, or
- you can `docker import` the tar

Option 2 in one step would be

```
tar -c * | docker import - minidebian:raw
```

If you create a 'raw' image (without metadata) from the tar file, then you can add the docker metadata with a simple dockerfile

```
FROM minidebian:raw

LABEL description="Minimal Debian 8 image"
MAINTAINER Ignacio Núñez Hernanz <nacho@ownyourbits.com>

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

, and building the final image

```
docker build . -t minidebian:latest
```

Taken from this guide

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/19/creating-a-minimal-debian-container-for-docker/

If you need to create a Debian container, you can follow that guide. It uses `debootstrap`.

Also, there are already-made containers that you can use

- The one provided by the guide (small!)

  docker pull ownyourbits/minidebian
- The official ones from Debian

  docker pull debian:jessie

  docker pull debian:jessie-slim # smaller than jessie